# Can a question be a duplicate if it's totally different?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

There is this question: [Why does changing a css class name break the styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24835697/1016716)
that reminded me of this question: [Why row won't show up?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14722639/1016716)
but only after the answer was given, which was that it was caused by an ad blocker.

So then, can two questions that are totally different, but just happen to have the same answer, be duplicates? Should the latest one be closed?

Comment: Even if not duplicates, the close reason "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, *this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers*. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting." (emphasis mine) seems relevant.

Comment: But in this case, that is not a good reason to close the question. The issue may not be reproducible by people who have different software configurations, but that doesn't mean it won't be of help to future readers who do. I mean, the chance that other people won't run into the same problem is not zero, judged by the fact that there are multiple questions about the same problem!

Comment: I would at least refer to the other question so it will be linked on the right side as similar. Having an identical answer they must be similar in some aspect.

Comment: "Can a question be a duplicate if it's totally different?" By definition, no.

Comment: SO needs duplicates to stay current. We just have bad apples that think they are do gooders by keeping us in the past.

Comment: Having the same answer does not imply duplicates.  What's 100/2? Well its 50.  How many states are there in the US?  Also 50.  Are these questions duplicates because they share the same answer? *Absolutely not*

Comment: @wnnmaw What about the two questions being asked about? They sound completely different, but they ended up having the exact same cause. Do you think Ben would have had any issues with his question being closed as a duplicate of that other one if it had an answer stating that AdBlock Plus blocked elements with certain class names that might indicate they're ads, and had a link to the list of blocked classes? Or do you think he would have considered his question resolved?

Comment: @Ajedi32 The duplicate message, "This question already has an answer..." implies yes, if the answers are the same.  The question just happens to have been worded differently.

Comment: Having the same answer lightly implies duplicated questions. It doesn’t guarantee them, but I’d definitely say that these two questions are duplicates (not to say much of having that particular answer; they’re the same problem, and one has more information and is generally nicer).

Comment: By definition, a duplicate is an exact copy, so it is impossible for question B to be a duplicate of A if question B differs at all from question B. If you want to get incredibly pedantic, even a copy & paste is not a duplicate because it has a different asker.

Comment: Not at all, a dupe is a copy of something, if the user asks the same question such as not being able to read a key from an array, and there is another question that has an accepted answer, that's a dupe. But 2 separate questions are definitely not a dupe, there are a hundred ways to get to the same place per say, same with questions, there are tons of questions that can produce the same answer.

Comment: [You accepted the wrong answer. Nice going.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266244/can-a-question-be-a-duplicate-if-its-totally-different/266246#comment65348_266272)

Comment: OK, I understand, I delete my question..

Answer (score -36, accepted):

Since I've been discussing this a bit in comments on [Cerbrus' answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266246/552438) I figure I'd post my own competing answer, since I have the opposite opinion on whether they should be closed.

In the general case, based on my interpretation of this statement

> Now, notice that this is subtly different from saying "If that other question isn't asking the exact same thing as yours..." That's because **the proof is in the answers**. If the question looks the same, but the answers aren't solving the asker's problem, *that is not a dupe* – that is a legitimate new question. Neither the person asking nor the person who lands from Google cares if the question has been asked before: they care if it has been answered.

taken from [Changes to "close as duplicate" (part deux)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166707/changes-to-close-as-duplicate-part-deux), I'd say that yes, two seemingly totally different questions should be considered duplicates if they share the same answer. The above quote is obviously dealing with the opposite case than this question, but I would argue that if the "proof is in the answers" and two apparently identical questions with different answers **aren't** duplicates, then two apparently different questions with identical answers **are** duplicates.

There are lots of times when a user comes along and wants to solve some problem they're having, and they use all kinds of words to describe the problem and what they want to achieve. And for all of those questions the answer essentially boils down to needing to use technique X. For example, anybody who regularly visits the [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) tag will know that there's constantly new questions being asked that can be answered using event delegation. They might look like totally different questions, but the same underlying principle can be applied to solve all of them.

However, make sure to also consider the quality of the answer(s) involved. If a question has already been answered elsewhere, but it's a pretty short, not particularly informative, answer that may not be useful to somebody who is trying to apply the principles to another similar issue, don't close as a duplicate. There's no point creating sign posts to crap content.

---

With regard to this specific case, "Why row won't show up?" seems like the worse question, and it also has the worse answer. If I was going to vote to close I'd pick that one as the candidate for closure.

Comment: So, according to you: _"yes, two seemingly totally different questions should be considered duplicates if they share the same answer."_: 2 totally different questions that can both be answered / solved by saying _"Reboot your PC"_ should be closed as duplicates.

Comment: @Cerbrus "Reboot your PC" is probably a crap answer, and may very well indicate that the question is either low quality or off-topic. If, however, the answer was something along the lines of "This is caused by problem X, <a fair amount of information on what problem X is so that people can recognise it and know what it affects>. You'll need to reboot your PC to resolve it." then yes, I'd say they should both be closed as duplicates, because they have "problem X" in common **and** the person asking the duplicate question can see how it addresses their question too.

Comment: You're missing my point. I don't think you can generalize two completely __different problems__ that can be solved by following the same set of instructions.

Comment: @Cerbrus And I think that, if the set of instructions is explicit and explained enough (i.e. significantly more detailed than "Reboot your PC"), you can get to a point where two seemingly completely different problems can be objectively seen to be the **same** problem manifesting in subtly different ways. Not always, of course, but sometimes. That said, I think we've both made our different positions perfectly clear, we seem unable to come to an agreement (which is fine), and there's probably little value in cluttering comments any further.

Comment: Hm.. this is the answer I agree most with, but if I accept it, that means I should VTC, right? You know what, I'll follow your advice and VTC the older one.

Comment: -1 -- Having the same answer doesn't imply being duplicates. I believe this was stated already thousand of times from both the community and the moderators.

Comment: What is 1 + 1? 2. What is 1 * 2? 2. Guess that's a duplicate question.

Comment: ~checks profile~ Yeah, on SciFi.SE, we use "same answer->probably duplicate".  Not sure how much it really applies here...

Comment: That two questions with different answers are no duplicates does not automatically imply that questions with the same answers are duplicates.

Comment: I will stand by my decision to accept this answer.

Comment: @MrLister: Could you elaborate on why you agree with this answer the most?

Comment: @Cerbrus Because the example questions in my post above were the reason to ask here; I wasn't just using them as examples. Both questions asked "Why ... ?" and both answers were "Because ...". That is a whole different situation than the contrived examples for "questions that incidentally both have the same answer". So I made up my mind, I did close one of them as a duplicate and that is that. Not saying that the other answer doesn't have merit. Not even saying that the other answer might not be applicable in more situations! But this is my answer.

Comment: I was only asking for clarification, didn't meant to step on your toes...

Comment: Every time this discussion comes up, someone drags out the same old straw chestnut for another beating, "So, these two questions that can be answered with the same three words are duplicates now, huh?" **NO**, they're not, because the full, real, quality answer to them _isn't_ the same. Answers that short don't indicate duplication (and are probably crap answers anyways); what indicates duplication is the _underlying problem_ being the same, and thus the _solution_ being the same. See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/85727/

Comment: You accepted the wrong answer.  Nice going.

Comment: @JoshCaswell It's not a strawman when the question here on meta is *'So then, can two questions that are totally different, but just happen to have the same answer, be duplicates?'* - the answer to that is clearly no - that includes those cases you are dismissing. You are saying that 'If knowing the answer to one question means knowing the answer to the other question, one is a duplicate of the other', which is valid, but different to the question at hand here. This whole thing is skewed by the fact that 'totally different' means different things to different people.

Comment: [Cerbrus's first comment here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266244/can-a-question-be-a-duplicate-if-its-totally-different/266272?noredirect=1#comment64733_266272) is a straw man, @Lattyware, because no-one is claiming that the _bare text_ of the (extremely short) answer is the determining factor for duplication. The _contents_ of the (detailed) answer are, however, strongly indicative that you've got two questions about the same problem, and thus duplicates.

Answer (score 83):

Two questions that can be answered by the same answer aren't necessarily duplicates, and shouldn't be closed as such.

## Only if the *question* is a duplicate, you should close it as such.

There's a question on the Stack Exchange meta that has a more in-depth answer about duplicates:
[How should duplicate questions be handled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled)
As well as [this StackOverflow blog post.](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/handling-duplicate-questions/)

The blog post mentions three classes of duplicate questions:

- **Cut-and-paste duplicate questions**.
  (The very definition of exact duplicates.)
- **Accidental duplicates**.
  (Questions that aren't copy and paste, but they cover the exact same ground as an earlier Stack Overflow question.)
- **Borderline duplicates**.
  (in the same ballpark as a previous question, but have subtle differences that may make them legitimately standalone questions.)

*"Two questions that are totally different"* don't fall in any of those categories. As such, they shouldn't be closed as duplicates.

Comment: How about something a bit more recent (that I think says the exact opposite) than a blog post from 5 years ago? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166707/changes-to-close-as-duplicate-part-deux

Comment: Thanks, @AnthonyGrist. I don't think that changes this answer, though: _"the proof is in the answers. **If the question looks the same**, but the answers aren't solving the asker's problem, that is not a dupe"_ The point is that the questions don't look the same _at all_. OP's asking about _completely different_ questions that happen to have the same answer.

Comment: The point is that **the proof is in the answers**. If they look like totally different questions, but knowing the answer to one allows you to answer the other, they're duplicates.

Comment: The answers are only relevant __if__ the question looks the same, in the first place, @AnthonyGrist

Comment: I disagree, I think there's a tipping point (generally based on the quality of the answers involved) where two seemingly different questions share an answer and should be closed as duplicates. There are plenty of questions that might look totally different but boil down to needing the same underlying principle to form the solution. Just look at the number of jQuery questions that can be solved using event delegation, but are phrased in a hundred different ways. Or the number of Java questions that just boil down to not knowing to use `.equals()` instead of the `==` operator to compare strings.

Comment: I agree, but __that is not what this question is about__. This question is about questions that are on the "different" side of that tipping point. I mean, what about _"totally different"_ did you miss? It's simple, really. If the two questions are indeed _"totally different"_, they shouldn't be closed as duplicates.

Comment: Also, @AnthonyGrist: That tipping point you described is covered in the __Borderline duplicates.__ point.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Imo, that's out of the scope of the question. This question isn't asking how to handle near-duplicates, rather how to handle nowhere-near-duplicates that happen to have the same answer. Those can't be merged and shouldn't be closed as duplicates.

Comment: Just an aside: Just because two questions look completely different, they can still be essentially the same question, though in disguise. In that case, the one declared duplicate might be a superb sign-post and thus a valuable contribution.

Comment: This answer assumes that the asker identified and entered their actual question. This is most often not the case. Making text bold doesn't make it true.

Comment: @CodeCaster I'm disappointed that you didn't make that last sentence bold.

Comment: How can I answer questions that are `borderline duplicates`, if my answer for both questions is essentially the same, without being reprimanded for it?! Or what other options do I have? See also http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315293/answering-borderline-duplicate-questions

Comment: I think the overall problem with allowing unrelated questions to be duplicates is how the site works.  Flagging a question as a dupe doesn't link to *the answer*.  It links to *the question*, and that's confusing.  The asker is going to follow a link to a seemingly unrelated topic, and will assume the person marking the dupe misunderstood the question.  In other words, the behavior of SO is such that it will not be clear by the dupe flag alone what the moderation means.  You'll get people getting questions closed a duplicates and *not understanding what the duplication was*. That can't happen.

Comment: @Cerbrus: can you add what is writen by Jeff Atwood (co-founder) and that majority of closer seems to have not read ! 
There’s often benefit to having multiple subtle variants of a question around, as people tend to ask and search using completely different words, and the better our coverage, the better odds our fellow programmers can find the answer they’re looking for.
I think that a survey with impartial analyse in necessary because this post is totally impartial. Why ? Just see which answer has been accepted !

Answer (score 7):

> So then, can two questions that are totally different, but just happen to have the same answer, be duplicates? Should the latest one be closed?

No. Questions are generally asked by describing the **symptoms** (or **signs**) of a problem. Answers, especially good ones, tend to describe the **causes** of the problem (and their solutions).

The same root cause can manifest itself with different symptoms in different environments, and the same symptoms can have multiple possible causes (depending on the context).

Merging all possible symptoms into a single cause doesn't make sense. People search by identifying what the problem is, not by knowing the cause in advance (otherwise they wouldn't ask or search). In addition, despite sharing the same cause, one of the question may have a possible solution (in future answers) that is not necessarily applicable to the other question (although they currently share similar answers).

Comment: However, it makes sense to have all the various symptoms point at one cause (and solution) otherwise when the solution needs tweaking you only have to edit one answer rather than half a dozen or more.

Comment: @ChrisF, true, but in some circumstances, you may have a solution that's more adapted to one of the questions, and simply wouldn't apply to the other.

Comment: This answer definitely mistakes what the duplicate system is - it's not a 'delete this', it's a 'turn this into a pointer'. Duplicates allows you to associate multiple **symptoms** with a single **cause**. If your answers can be meaningfully different, the cause or situation must be different enough to make it not a duplicate.

Comment: @lattyware, the problem is that there are very few *exact* duplicates. Very often, one little sentence explaining a different content can open the door to a secondary solution. While the main solution may be the same, preventing other, more adapted answers by closing the question doesn't help.

Comment: For example, if you cough in winter, typical causes may be a viral or bacterial infection. Prescribing antibiotics because they worked for someone else with similar symptoms isn't necessarily the solution. (Of course, clarifying the circumstances via comments can help.)

Comment: I'd say there are very few *non-trivial exact duplicates* - I've seen about a million 'What is [:] in python?' questions, which are all solved by the same answer. The issue here is that 'totally different' doesn't have inherent meaning. If you take it as 'different, but possibly with the same root cause', then sure, it's possible, but 'totally different' becomes a meaningless phrase compared to 'different'. If you take it as 'different to such an extent the answers matching is coincidence', then the answer is obviously no by simple counter-example.

Comment: @Lattyware, true, but it's also helpful to build answers that are tailored to the vocabulary in the question (which may be incorrect). Often, the answers in the duplicate might not make any sense to the asker or anyone reading the question. Making sure the answers match the questions is actually essential in a Q&A system.

Comment: @Bruno That can be true, although generally avoidable by a strong answer the other end of the dupe link.

Answer (score 6):

The answer to both 2+3 and 15/3 is 5. But I don't think they should be treated as duplicate questions...

Comment: See [my comment on Anthony Grist's answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266244/can-a-question-be-a-duplicate-if-its-totally-different#comment65028_266272). Your answer is a straw man.

Comment: Well, to be honest, my response wasn't much of an answer, more along the lines of a comment. I was just suggesting that a duplicate answer doesn't imply a duplicate question because there isn't a 1:1 mapping of questions to answers (that's why you can't always derive a single question from an answer - although I know that's kinda what contestants are expected to do on Jeopardy...)

Comment: Of course there can be two questions that are essentially identical, but only phrased differently. For example, "How many licks to the center of a tootsie pop?", would be a duplicate of "What is the number of times one's tongue must graze the surface of a chocolate filled sucker in order to reach the middle?" Is the same question. But not because the answer is the same. Identical answers only indicate two questions COULD be duplicate questions. Not necessarily that they ARE duplicate questions.

Comment: The point is that nobody's claiming that the _text_ of the answer is how you determine whether questions are duplicates. The solution itself, the _meaning_ of the answer, is what tells you that you're looking at two expressions of the same problem.

Comment: Well... yeah. If you're going to wax philosophical and define the complete "meaning" of an answer to include the question. For example, the two answers: "15/3 is 5 because 3 goes into 15 5 times" and "2+3 is 5 because the addition of 2 objects to 3 existing ones sums to 5 objects" then what you said is true because the answer always includes the question in some form. However, I still think you could say that 5 is an answer to both questions, and the number 5 has the same representation or meaning in both cases. -- But the reason for which you arrived at that answer includes the question.

Answer (score 1):

For me the fundamental question here is: What is the purpose of the Stackoverflow community of sites? To answer questions, right?

Two people may have different questions that end up having the same answer. But if the questions are different, even though the answer is in the same domain (see the answer by @Anthony Grist re jQuery and event delegation) it is often worth having both questions because they cover different aspects of the same problem. And a different problem statement may imply a different angle not understood.

Let me give an example.

```
Question 1: I was driving along and suddenly my car seemed to lose all power and
the engine stalled. Now it won't start. I can hear the starter motor but there
seems to be no spark.

Question 2: My car worked fine last night. But this morning it simply won't
start. The starter turns but it does not start.
```

A likely answer to both of these questions is that you have run out of petrol. But the two questions do address slightly different aspects of the same problem. To someone familiar with cars (and familiar with running out of petrol) it may seem obvious that the two issues refer to the same problem. But to someone unfamiliar with the domain this may not be obvious.

Looking at two questions and a set of answers for each one could sometimes conclude that they are duplicates because the issue and/or resolution is the same. But often this fact only becomes clear after the question has been answered. Or it may be clear to someone who already knows the answer, i.e. someone who understands the problem and the different ways it may manifest.

Are we trying to preserve storage space here? Duplicates should be marked as such, I think we all agree on that. But when there is any doubt I would say keep both questions. I would rather have an extra question that may be viewed by someone understanding the problem domain as a duplicate but that just so happens to describe the problem as I understand it.

Comment: _"What is the purpose of the Stackoverflow community of sites? To answer questions, right? [...] But the two questions do address slightly different aspects of the same problem"_ - no, SO wants to be a knowledge base. We're not here to answer every invocation of _"How do I split a string on [space|comma|underscore|pipe]"_ or _"How to parse a date in format X"_. We need one, canonical string splitting question with valuable answers. _"Are we trying to preserve storage space here?"_ - no, we want to prevent the spreading and duplication of knowledge. Closing questions as duplicates helps this.

Comment: @CodeCaster, "*SO wants to be a knowledge base*", true, but by having people ask and answer questions. As far as SO is concerned, you can't easily distinguished the means from the end. Canonical questions are a noble, but generally unachievable goal. Either they become too long, listing *all* the symptoms and turning into tutorials, or they're succinct, but require knowing how to describe the problem with the exact terminology (i.e. knowing the problem very well in advance). There isn't really a way to merge and associate fragments of answers for similar questions on SO, to complement dup.

Comment: Specific example of two very different questions with potentially the same answer, which I recently asked (before realizing I could use the same answer): http://stackoverflow.com/q/28994627/1390430 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/28888418/1390430. I almost went to mark my second question as a duplicate when I realized my mistake, but then realized the two questions, on the surface, have nothing to do with each other.