# Can I flag similar questions?

Tags: discussion

Look into this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25093258/how-to-split-string-into-textboxes-in-vb-net. he was asking for  **split string into Textboxes in VB.NET** and here is a similar question(**Split a String into 2 Variables**) having many answers in the link
[Split a String into 2 Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10788085/split-a-string-into-2-variables).

If I raised a flag in this situation, will the flag be helpful or not?

Comment: Although both questions are readily answered by *Use split() (and read the manual next time)*, one is effectively symmetrical to the other (the first is about splitting text from a variable to several text boxes, the second about splitting a text box's value into several variables). They're strongly related indeed, but I don't think they're worth being closed as duplicates of one another. Your mileage of course may vary.

Comment: the basic operation is spiting and assigning, only the LHS(Left hand side) is different, that's why am askinng

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current stance on duplicates [seems to be](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266244/can-a-question-be-a-duplicate-if-its-totally-different) (according to the votes) that indeed the question must be an *exact duplicate* (to which I do not entirely agree, but that's a different story). The questions being asked in the question you link to could be:

- How do I read a textbox's contents?
- How do I split a string on comma?
- How do I access array elements?
- How can I assign a string to a textbox's Text property?

Questions that could be asked after reading that question:

- Is this format fixed, do all lines have 5 elements?
- What do you want to do when the textbox has multiple lines?
- What have you tried?

This means the question you link to should be closed as either "Too broad" or "Unclear what you're asking", with perhaps a comment linking to the question you suggested as duplicate.

I think we should not make it SO's problem to refine questions into smaller parts that *do* have duplicates, that is OP's task.