# Regurgitating answers for subtly different questions

Tags: discussion

So, a few days I came across this question:

[Force C# to load an assembly that is referenced only in a cshtml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39334206/force-c-sharp-to-load-an-assembly-that-is-referenced-only-in-a-cshtml-file)

My immediate instinct was to dupehammer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9456207/how-to-add-assembly-in-web-config-file-of-mvc-4), but I wasn't absolutely convinced that the question was an exact dupe, so instead I posted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9456207/how-to-add-assembly-in-web-config-file-of-mvc-4) as a comment, hoping that someone else might pick up the dupe-iness of it.

This has now lead to requests in the comments for me to expand the information contained in the linked question into its own answer (because "comments fade" whatever that means).

I don't feel this is the right approach, and that adding the link in the comments is action enough. I don't want to write an answer, because there is a perfectly adequate answer in the linked to question.

What's best here?

Comment: Either it's a dupe, and that answer answers the question, and it should be closed as such, or it's not a dupe, and commenting on someone else's answer saying that they should have used the dupe's answer is kind of silly.

Comment: IMHO It's not a dupe.

OP question was: `How do I load an assembly?`. One of many possible answers is `Add a reference`. That does not make the question a duplicate of `How to add a reference in web.config`.

Comment: [Enjoy your mighty hammer responsibly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230865/increase-close-vote-weight-for-gold-tag-badge-holders). This means that as a wielder, I need to be more than extra-double sure that what I'm looking at is a dupe. If there's any doubt, I can no longer rely on the crowd to confirm my suspicions, therefore, my best option (IMO) is to post the link of the dupe and let the more democratic nature of 5 votes to pass.

Comment: The OP got 3 answers with no guidance which one is best.  High odds that you helped him make up his mind.  Well done, move on.

Answer (score 1):

I think that providing a link in a comment is perfectly adequate if you're not certain and aren't going to make your own answer. This helps populate the "linked questions" sidebar, and makes it easier if other people want to close as a dupe. Alternatively, it might help another person expand upon their own answer.

I wouldn't repost the content from someone's answer in the comments, since there's no way to properly quote things there. It also strays into the territory of answering in the comments, which is annoying to say the least.

The reason why comments are considered "fading" is because moderators or 6 people with flags can delete them. Don't get too attached to comments.

Answer (score -2):

If you are on the fence at all, just go ahead and vote it as a dupe. Unless you've earned the "dupehammer" in one of the tags on the question, additional votes will be required to make it official, which provides a bit of a crowd-sourced safety net. Additionally, the OP can always get the question reopened if it's not truly a dupe, by editing it to highlight the specific issues as play that make it a unique case.

Comment: They do have the dupehammer: *My immediate instinct was to dupehammer*.

Comment: Ah. Missed that. Still, the point about the OP being able to edit and submit it to be reopened applies. Nothing is ever set in stone.

Answer (score -2):

**Are two different questions a duplicate if they have the same answer?**

Already asked here: [Does the same answer imply that the questions should be closed as duplicate?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292329/does-the-same-answer-imply-that-the-questions-should-be-closed-as-duplicate) and here:
[Can a question be a duplicate if it's totally different?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266244/can-a-question-be-a-duplicate-if-its-totally-different)

The most upvoted answers agree that: **Only if the *question* is a duplicate, you should close it as such.**

So, you should write a new answer, *even if the answer is a duplicate to another question's answer*. Citing and linking to the original answer is considered polite.

If don't have the time to write an answer, then just leave a comment on the question: `try this link`

Finally, commenting on someone else answer, saying your *link* is better, is not constructive and only brings chatty discussion. If you had written your own answer in the first place, you would have plenty of space to elaborate on why your answer is better and provide great guidance to the OP.

Comment: The trouble here isn't that we have two questions that have the same answer in the 1 + 1 == 2 and 4 - 2 == 2 sense, where it is clearly a stretch to say that the question is a duplicate ([1st link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292329/does-the-same-answer-imply-that-the-questions-should-be-closed-as-duplicate)), nor is it a "totally different" question ([2nd link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266244/can-a-question-be-a-duplicate-if-its-totally-different)). Personally, I see the question as a duplicate, but I can also appreciate the subtle differences that make it unique...

Comment: ...I wanted to share the information in the other question with the OP (which I would have normally communicated via a close vote), wasn't willing to write an answer that would mostly be a cut'n'paste job, nor close because of the useful information that you had added in your answer. This leaves another option of just keeping my mouth shut, which, to me isn't in the spirit of information share. Bear in mind that I haven't spent too much time researching the merits of each approach, so simply stated my preference for the method that I linked to. Personally, I feel that my contribution was...

Comment: ...beneficial to the OP and anyone who subsequently comes to the question. I don't buy the "comments are transient" argument, and unless there's a rogue moderator deleting useful comments (this applies equally to answers really), it's my belief that the comment will remain there forever. Handy for anyone to see. With a bit more time on my hands, I might have reviewed both methods (web.config vs code), but as things stand, I didn't have enough to add to make a fully-fledged answer.

Comment: The clincher here that I believe makes the question a dupe is the final sentence of the question "I really don't want to leave the dummy line in the code." which only leaves the web.config option. However, your answer is useful in its own right, so it would be a shame to orphan it with my dupehammer.

Comment: IMO, leaving a comment in the question is the way to go if you were short on time. The OP after reading the comment, if useful, should write its self-answer with your proposal. My answer was not perfect, but I don't see how your comment on my answer was useful... well.. eventually it was because it pushed me to improve my answer... But IMO it would have been just simpler and less conflictive if you just copy/paste the other answer into a new one. Proper Quote/Copy/Paste is not a sin in this case.

Comment: Closing as dupe I think is worse because the questions are different. They are not subtle differences at all. They only share the answer.  And dupe questions are eventually deleted.

Comment: mm, I was wrong about dup questions being deleted... I still believe they are not dupes. At least not in the current form of the old question.

Comment: I still differ with you about the dupe-iness of the question, but I'm glad that the information I shared was good for the OP and good for you to significantly improve your own answer. In a similar situation in the future, I will post more informative comments that don't leave room for confusion. Differences in opinion are a regular part of SO life, and after my first bad dupehammer, I'm far more cautious about my close votes now because if I feel there's any room for wiggle, better to leave it to the democracy. Maybe we should move back to answering questions now? :)

Comment: Maybe in this cases where your dupehammer is too much, you can leave a regular comment `possible duplicate of ` as if it were a close vote and move on. BTW, yes, lets go back to questions now.

Comment: In a surprising turn of events, the OP confirmed late that he does not even have a `web.config` file, which proves my point that is was not a dupe. cc @spender