# Different questions with the same answer - best practice?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Sometimes questions aren't exactly the same but they touch on a common concern and share a single answer.

A few good examples include:

- [Using static file serving instead of Websockets/SSE to keep clients in sync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49326970/using-static-file-serving-instead-of-websockets-sse-to-keep-clients-in-sync)
- [At what point are Web Sockets less efficient than Polling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44731313/at-what-point-are-web-sockets-less-efficient-than-polling)
- [Does HTTP/2 make websockets obsolete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28582935/does-http-2-make-websockets-obsolete)
- [WebSockets protocol vs HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14703627/websockets-protocol-vs-http)
- [Why use AJAX when WebSockets is available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10377384/why-use-ajax-when-websockets-is-available)

Lately I've started getting lazy explaining the same thing over and over again so I link to existing answers / threads instead of writing the whole thing again (for example, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49336209/4025095))

I thought this would help SEO and future developers will have a better chance at finding an answer before posting a question.

Instead, this got me down voted and criticized (see the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49326970/using-static-file-serving-instead-of-websockets-sse-to-keep-clients-in-sync/49336209?noredirect=1#comment86055192_49336209)).

I wonder, **at what point to we mark a question as a duplicate**? Is it when a question shares an answer with a different question or when the question itself describes the same circumstances?

And **what do we do when different questions share the same answer**? is it better to repeat an existing answer or link to the original one?

Perhaps a "related" answers feature should be considered (in addition to the existing related questions)?

**EDIT**:

I accepted Brad's answer, with the added information in the comments - that in cases where there's no specific details to be added to an existing answer, commenting on the question with links to the relevant SO answers should be preferred over posting new answer.

However, this raises the question of a new **feature request: adding the ability to answer a question using an existing *answer*** (with the answer's link being attached).

**Clarification**:

Currently, a "belongs-to" relationship is assumed, where an answers "belongs to" a single question.

However, what if an existing answer will answer a new question? (i.e., the answer "42" answers the old question "meaning of like" and a new question "7 X 6")...?

I would love to see a feature that allows me to recommend an existing answer to a new question and have OP and developers accept or vote on my recommendation.

Comment: Related: [Can a question be a duplicate if it's totally different?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266244/can-a-question-be-a-duplicate-if-its-totally-different)

Comment: @jpp thank you for the link, however, the thread you link to doesn't resolve the issue. In effect, the question in those cases is "is this a duplicate question?" where in my example the questions are clearly different (though they share a common thread which makes the answer the same). My question here also asks "what do we do when different questions share the same answer?" and I wish to discuss links and other ways to better inform developers (rather than repeat a watered down version of better answers).

Comment: Of course it doesn't answer your question. That's why it's marked as "Related" - rather than "Possible duplicate".

Comment: @jpp - Oh, sorry about that :-)

Comment: The accepted answer isn't complete. It doesn't cover the situation when the answer is given by *another* person. I think this information is critical and should be added to the answer. I get from comments under the answer that using comments in this case is preferable. But comments are for clarifying, not for answering.

Comment: @BogdanLukiyanchuk - Thank you for pointing this out. Do you have a recommendation about the best way to remedy the situation?

Comment: I'm quite new here. I don't know traditions of SO good enough and what is acceptable here.

Comment: @BogdanLukiyanchuk - that's fine. I've been here for three years or so and sometimes I still feel new to this. I think that editing my question with enough details should be enough. This way, reading the answer and the question would be enough. Also, it's quite common for comments on an answer to provide more details when editing someone else's answer would be rude.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Different questions with the same answer are still different questions.  The questions you have posted are different enough that they should stand.

Note that when answering the question, you can reference your answers on other questions.  Just be sure that your answer is *specific to the question asked*.

Comment: This is a very polite way to go about it, but sometimes it feels that addressing the specifics in the question is like spoon feeding - especially if the same specifics are covered in the existing answers (a good example is the newline consumption issue in `scanf`).

Comment: @Myst If you're not answering the specifics of the question, don't bother answering... write a tutorial or book or something instead.  Also note that you can always leave a comment with links to other questions you find relevant, as you did with the question you're posting about here.

Comment: good point. I'll accept the answer based on the added practice (when there's no specific details to be added to an existing answer, commenting with links to the relevant SO answers should be preferred over posting answer)... I do wonder if we should add the feature of flagging a question as closed due to existing answers. What do you think?

Comment: @Myst, questions should *not* be closed due to existing answers. Ever. Not trying to self-promote here, but look at this [perfectly good solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48731059/9209546) to a question *9 years old*, a solution not considered or seen by ~300k viewers of the question thus far. But one that future visitors *will* see.

Comment: @jpp - I think your rule ("questions should not be closed due to existing answers") assumes a belongs-to relationship (one answer belongs to one question). I think it would be great if I could suggest an existing answer to a new question and get OP and other developers to accept or vote on my suggestion.

Comment: @Myst, I can't force anyone to vote for my 9-years-late post. I post because I think it's improving SO as a resource. Even rep-hunters get tired of SO. Keep it interesting, learn new things. Rep might come or might not.

Comment: @jpp I'm happy for your approach, I think it's totally fair. I may have been foolish to use the word "closed", when I actually meant "marked as answered". Obviously I don't want to reject better answers that could improve SO's quality.

Answer (score 2):

I consider myself somewhat of a Google guru. I can usually find answers, but sometimes, you know what you want and how to describe it, but not the specific keywords that will yield the best results.

As an example. I needed to get the CPU load of a computer in a c# application. I initially searched for `C# Get CPU Utilization`, then found a few key words, started including `PerformanceCounter`, then as I realized that it only would give me an instantaneous reading I incorporated `average`, `seconds`. While I found hundreds of questions, none seemed to quite answer what I needed, and yet it would have been to some degree a duplicate question for me to ask since the only thing missing was an average.

After solving my problem, it seemed right to share the solution. But on which of the 360 questions (https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=performancecounter+%25+Processor+Time) should I share it? Maybe on the top Google search result? What about the first result when searching on StackOverflow? Maybe I should sort by newest?

My point is that there are multiple ways people search for answers, and when you want to help, putting your gem of an answer in a single spot and calling it a job well done isn't always good enough.

I agree that you don't want to clutter the site with spam, but of those 360, you could potentially call 50% or more of them duplicates, and yet it is beneficial to some degree to have them all there so that when people know what they want but not the right keywords they can still find relevant results.