# Are questions closed as duplicates eventually deleted?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

I asked a question that I was then able to find the answer to after reading through comments in similar questions. I answered my own question using information I learned in those comments: [Why does switching the base image in a multi-stage Docker build from distroless to alpine cause "exec user process caused: no such file or directory"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71262223/why-does-switching-the-base-image-in-a-multi-stage-docker-build-from-distroless)

But then my question was marked as a duplicate and closed (even though my original issue where I got the error message wasn't the same as the other question). It's important to me that my question continue to exist on Stack Overflow so that I can keep a reference to it via my Stack Overflow profile and return to it if I encounter the error again or if I need something formal to show a colleague.

Can I count on my question continuing to exist in the Stack Overflow system so that I can keep it for these purposes, or will it eventually be deleted and I'd need to make a backup of it somewhere?

Comment: They are only deleted if they get downvoted and deleted by the community (as questions need a score of -3 to accrue delete votes), or if they don't end up with a positive score (or answer with a positive score) and thus get deleted by the [roomba](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba). Positively received questions are not deleted.

Comment: It sounds like this might be a concern then. Since my question was deleted, it isn't searchable via Stack Overflow or crawled by Google (if I recall correctly). Also, I've noticed questions closed as duplicates aren't publicly accessible. I've tried sharing a link to a closed question before and I could see it because I was logged in, but an incognito window was instead redirected to the alleged duplicate.

Comment: Duplicates are definitely indexed; I get duplicates on my searches all the time.

Comment: Ah okay. There are still some things I'd like to know about duplicates. For example, I'm confused about why my question was closed as a duplicate. It happens to have the same solution (use alpine as the base image) but the circumstances are different from the question mine allegedly duplicated. The comment https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266244/can-a-question-be-a-duplicate-if-its-totally-different#comment64910_266244 (which was highly upvoted) is a perfect example of why I don't think my question should have been closed as a duplicate. Do you know how I'd dispute it being closed?

Comment: @MattWelke "It happens to have the same solution" is essentially the definition of duplicate on SO. If you want your question to be re-opened you need to explain why "the same solution" *did not* solve the problem inline in your question.

Comment: My concern is with discoverability. People search their problem, not the solution to their problem. They don't know the solution yet. For example, my problem was the error message "standard_init_linux.go:228: exec user process caused: no such file or directory" under certain circumstances. The question mine allegedly duplicated had different circumstances. If my question isn't indexed by Google, how are people who encounter that error message under the same circumstances I did going to find the information they need to solve their problem?

Comment: Put another way, if situation A and situation B both lead to problem C, which has solution D described in a SO question where the asker describes how situation A leads to problem C, is it a good idea to close a question describing situation B resulting in problem C having solution D as a duplicate? I like the idea of SO being a knowledge base, including documenting those situations, and I don't like the idea of a situation contributing to a problem someone is having not being indexed and therefore not being discoverable.

Comment: That situation is exactly the point of duplicate closure: That all different questions  with their different situations point to the appropriate solution. A duplicate closed question is effectively a signpost so that people do not have to do „a little more searching“ for a relation they don’t know about.

Comment: I wish SEDE exposed `PostHistory` for deleted posts - if that was the case, your question could've been answered with data, but alas... That said, in general, duplicates are not deleted if they have at least some value.

Comment: You could make it into a blog post (but not on [Medium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medium_(website)), please). Self-hosted, or if nothing else, then [Blogger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blogger_%28service%29) (though with Google you never know when they will shut the whole service down for some odd reason). It should not be in Q&A format, but you can tell an interesting (detective?) story instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [roomba](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) will automatically delete a question *closed as a duplicate* only if the question has no answers. Your question has an answer, so the roomba won't touch it (regardless of score of the question or answer) unless the answer gets deleted. So your question will likely continue to exist unless community members vote to delete it.

Even if the question did get deleted, you'd still be able to see it on your profile under your [deleted questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/deleted-questions/current) or [bookmarks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=bookmarks) if you bookmark it (though if the question is deleted, it'd likely become much more difficult to find through a search engine, which is how most people find existing questions). Users other than you wouldn't be able to see it anymore, unless they had the [10k reputation necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) to see deleted posts.

If a question has been closed as a duplicate but you think the answer contains useful information not present in the canonical question, you can consider posting an answer to the canonical question if you think it'd be of use to future readers, including yourself and colleagues. If the duplicate target isn't a close enough match for the situation in your question, you can also ask for the question to be reopened. (I'm not making a judgement on whether either of these approaches is the right move here - I'm not a SME - it's just an option to keep in mind.)

Comment: > If the duplicate target isn't a close enough match for the situation in your question, you can also ask for the question to be reopened.

Comment: This is my situation and this is what I decided to do. I edited my answer to remove the confusing reference to the other question (I think that's what may have given someone the impression mine duplicated it) and then voted for my question to be reopened. Thanks!

Comment: *"but you think the answer contains useful information not present in the canonical question, you can consider posting an answer to the canonical question if you think it'd be of use to future readers"*  - I read that and it makes me think you are suggesting it is okay to duplicate an answer. This is not what you are suggesting, is it?

Comment: @Gimby If the answer is tailored to the question, and not just a copy-paste from another one, yes, I think it's OK. If a novel approach is present on a 0-score closed question, and not present on a question which is the canonical target with much higher visibility, I do think describing the approach on the canonical as well is worthwhile to the community.